# TypeScript access definition without importing file

Tags: typescript

In my Angular app, I'm able to access Angular types by installing the package @types/angular. Then in my TS files, I'm able to do things like `timeout: ng.ITimeoutService` *without* having to import anything into my file. I can then run `tsc` and everything compiles just fine. VSCode also does not complain that it can't find `ng.ITimeoutService`.

However when I try to emulate this behavior with my own custom types, it doesn't work without me having to explicitly import the module in my file. Here's what I'm doing:

1. Create file `vendor/@types/custom/index.d.ts` with contents:

   `export declare class MyClass {...}`
2. In my **tsconfig.json**, I add this path to **typeRoots**:

   `"typeRoots": ["./vendor/@types/custom"]`

Now in my app file **./app/view.ts**, I try to do this:

`public myObject: MyClass`

However VSCode, as well as tsc, complain:

> Cannot find name 'MyClass'

I've even tried using references:

`/// <reference path="../vendor/@types/custom/index.d.ts" />`

But this gives the same result.

How do I access a type without importing its file, similar to how I'm able to access types in node_modules/@types without having to import them?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [global definitions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-d-ts.html). I'm pretty sure that's how libraries like angular do `ng.ITimeoutService`. However you might need to have your own namespace like below.

```
/*~ If your library has properties exposed on a global variable,
 *~ place them here.
 *~ You should also place types (interfaces and type alias) here.
 */
declare namespace myLib {
  //~ We can write 'myLib.timeout = 50;'
  let timeout: number;
}
```

### Edit

It seems that you can add a `global` class within a `types.d.ts` file. I'm using `typescript 3.8.3` in VSCode.

Here's my `types.d.ts`

```
// This is accesible anywhere now
declare class Aaaaa {
  myFunction();
}
```

Here's my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "es2016", "dom"],
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "src/types.d.ts"]
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

Warning: Global types are not a good idea (should be a last resort option). Also the global class cannot have any initializers on it, so the implementation has to be loaded globally somewhere else (usually via script tags in the browser).

Comment: Thanks, this gets me closer. But how if my definitions are generated automatically by `tsc` through `tsconfig.json`, how can I have automatically wrap the definitions in a namespace?

Comment: Also I appear to be able to access built-in types like Event, File, etc, without having to import them. These don't appear to have to do with namespaces. How are these picked up on by the compiler?

Comment: This still doesn't work for me. `Cannot find name X` if I don't import the module.